# group by id and merge data where is null

Tags: mysql

I have join multi table and get this result

```
project_id | title|phone   | office_phone 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
3          |a     |1       |NULL
4          |b     |Null    |1   
4          |b     |2       |Null
5          |c     |Null    |1
5          |c     |Null    |2
5          |c     |Null    |3
5          |c     |1       |Null  
5          |c     |2       |Null
```

Now i want group by project id and merge data where is null

I want output like this

```
project_id | title|phone   | office_phone 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
3          |a     |1       |NULL
4          |b     |2       |1   
5          |c     |1       |1
5          |c     |1       |2
5          |c     |1       |3
5          |c     |2       |1
5          |c     |2       |2
5          |c     |2       |3
```

how can i do this?

Comment: What will happen if your data has this row also:  `5 | c | 2 | null`? With which `office_phone` will that 2 be combined? Will it impact the combinations that were already made by the `phone`  value 1? The logic is not clear.

Comment: i update my question for `5 | c | 2 | null`

Comment: Is `title` functional dependent on `project_id`? Or is it possible that different `title` values can occur with the same `project_id`?

Comment: every project_id has only one title

Answer (score 0):

You need a full outer self join, but as MySql does not support the `full outer join` syntax, you'd have to revert to a `union` to achieve the same result:

```
select     a.project_id, a.title, a.phone, b.office_phone 
from       tbl as a
left join  tbl as b 
        on a.project_id = b.project_id
       and b.office_phone is not null
where      a.phone is not null
union
select     a.project_id, a.title, b.phone, a.office_phone 
from       tbl as a
left join  tbl as b
        on a.project_id = b.project_id
       and b.phone is not null
where      a.office_phone is not null
and        b.phone is null
order by 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

See it run on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc79aa/1).